# Enabling X on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, windows, xorg, configure

I've tried to activate X windows from the command line as root. The most recent attempt using 'sudo X -configure' also fails with the final message fbcon not found in /lib/modules/6.5.0_26generic, what to do?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you running?  Did you mean ..6.5.0-26-generic?

Comment: 20.04 LTS I believe. (5.15.0-101-generic when typing uname -r)

Comment: Linux 6.5.0-26generic is the one that X fails. Linux 5.15.0_101generic, everything works.

Comment: Do you have Nvidia  hw and which driver do you use?  The 6.5 kernel had some trouble with the older drivers, since it needs the gcc-12.